# drawing on an android activity

Tags: android

I am trying to put a background image and draw on top of that screen. I assumed activity will have a on draw method, but it does not have. it seems i need to use surfaceview. Can I put a surfaceview on top of the image view and make it transparent ? any example/tutorial i can refer to ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to draw, you need a [canvas](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html) which holds the draw calls.

Check chapter 4 from [Hallo Android by Ed Burnette](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9781934356562) for a tutorial on the same.

You could optionally draw your graphics or animations into a View object from your layout.

Read [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/index.html) for more details.